# How to install Psychonoauts through software-center?

Tags: 12.04, software-center, games

I have been trying to install Psychonauts through the Ubuntu Software Centre. The purchase went smoothly but the installation hangs on both my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop and laptop.

When purchasing the game it states '4.4 GB to download, 5.5 GB when installed'

When clicking on the progress tab in Ubuntu Software Centre it seems to be hanging at '2.1 GB of 130.6 MB' (This is NOT a typo). Anyone have any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

USC doesn't show progress occasionally when the download size is large. It could be still downloading in the background.

*If* there is network activity wait for it to finish and look for icon on Unity Dash.

You can see if there is network activity by opening System Monitor and going to the Resources tab.

Comment: Do you know if a bug has been reported on Launchpad, for the Software Center sometimes failing to show progress information during large downloads? If not, then someone who can reproduce this problem should [report the bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).